# RichTextBox hyperlink does not raise clicked event when the form is not focused

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

When the form is not focused, clicking a hyperlink inside a RichTextBox on the form does not raise a clicked event. I have to click twice. Is this by design? If it is bug, what is the most elegant solution? I want to raise the clicked event with a single click whether the form is focused or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use Richtextbox's mouse hover event. Like this,

```
private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.LinkText);
        }

private void richTextBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Focus();
        }
```

**Result** (I set form's TopMost property true to show focus or not clearly. Btw you can track from form's header),

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: This would work, but couldn't this also produce an undesired effect when the user just moves over the link and the form accidentally gets focused?

Comment: Form lost it's focus so you have to click twice to richtextbox, in this solution hovering over richtextbox focuses the form automatically, what you said conflicts with your question. Yes just hover will focus, but otherwise you need to focus form by yourself. @Loser

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
Mouse_Enter
form1.getfocus
```

I'm sure you know the mouse enter event so yeah doing something like that should work....

Answer (score 0):

You have to click twice because the form is not in focus; first click brings the form in focus, second one fires the `LinkClicked` event of the `RichTextBox` control.

You can set the form to focus once mouse cursor is within its boundaries. Add the following code to the constructor of the form:

```
MouseEnter += (s, e) => Focus();
```

The hyperlink is then clicked while the form is in focus, and the `LinkClicked` event will fire from the first click, as desired.